# Candy Crush Saga

Tags: store, games

I've been waiting a long time for Candy Crush Saga, I've found some games that's like the official candy crush, but it's not so good. Does someone know when Candy Crush Saga comes to Windows Phone?

Answer (score 4):

It took a while, but [Candy Crush Saga is now available](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=aebbdef8-1792-488b-a7be-7596a1720166) in the store for Windows Phone 8, at least.